# jquery intermittently fails object lookups

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, sharepoint, yahoo-finance

I am working on a page that is ultimately shown as content in a sharepoint page. 
This is retrieving stock quotes from yahoo.

The page itself works 100% of the time
The Sharepoint (SP) page hosting my page works in IE ~90% of the time
The Sharepoint (SP) page hosting my page works in FF ~80% of the time
The Sharepoint (SP) page hosting my page works in Chrome ~5% of the time

Id like to focus on the Chrome scenario.

The failure comes in the callback function.

I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

The offending line is as follows

```
$("#" + quote.symbol + " .tkrPrice").text('$' + quote.AskRealtime);
```

I have read posts about Ready() and noConflict(). I have tried replacing $ with jQuery and that really doesnt seem to affect anything.

Here are a few things to consider

1. jQuery is successfully invoked before the api call to yahoo. its not a problem loading that file.
2. The network is sometimes pokey, but the page by itself works. So i am reluctant to blame the network for timing issues.
3. The object being selected absolutely exists at the time of the call. Its not a write the html then reference it timing type issue.
4. The error is in the callback from the yahoo api.
5. The SP page itself has a lot going on. I dont have a lot of insight into what exactly that is, but I will characterize it as a complicated page.

Im flumoxed. The logic is correct but clearly its something to do with timing. And something about Chrome emphasizes the problem.

Im looking for some debugging ideas...

tyia

Greg

Comment: Have you looked at the logs during the request?

Comment: that error message doesn't match that line... Are you sure that's where the error originates?

Comment: @kevinB - you are correct. At various points I was playing w/ jQuery and $ functions. This was in response to articles about Ready().  The message does come from that line. Thanks for pointing that out. Ill change the message so its not confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested I test to make sure jQuery was still loaded at the time of the callback.

This suggestion floored me, but since I had no ideas, I was grateful for something to try.

using this test it does appear jQuery is unloaded after the api call.

```
 function jqIsLoaded(){
            if (typeof jQuery == "undefined") return 0;
            return 1;
        }
```

My solution was to test for jQuery and dynamically load it if it was not loaded. 
Again, this is only necessary within a SP page. I have to assume it is something going on with the template of the page.